# Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService

Tags: java, grails

I am using grails and google youtube api( https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#AuthSub_for_Web_Applications) to fetch details about videos uploaded by users. But as soon as I try to initialize YouTubeService class as :

```
String emailID="XXXX@gmail.com"//this is the id with which i registered for developer key
String DeveloperKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" //developer key given by google
YouTubeService service=new YouTubeService(emailID,DeveloperKey)
//I am done using appName,clientId(given by google) as the first parameter to the 
YouTubeService but nothing helped
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaMultipart
//I can see this MediaMultipart file in the said destination in one of the included jars.
Originally it was complaining about com.google.collections.common.Maps but then i
added google.collections.1-rc.jar. I also tried adding guava.jar as read from various
forums but that could not solve my problem
```

If I reload the page, the error changes to

```
Class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService
```

I have included all the required jars( http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list) but this problem is not getting solved. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `javax.mail` and `com.google.guava` dependencies that are required by `gdata-java-client`.